# Query running in the workbench being much faster than in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysqljs

I'm running the **same query** (in the **same database**) on nodejs (npm/package/**mysql**) and mysql workbench and the execution time is absurdly different.

Follows the execution duration data:

- **nodejs**: 22468.275ms (**22,5 seconds**)
- **mysql workbench**: duration 0,019 sec / fetch 0,147 sec

db.config

```
{ "connectionLimit" : 10, "host" : "localhost", "user" : "root", "password" : "root", "database" : "db" }
```

other information:

- the mysql is running within a docker
- the main table of query has 9.500.000 records
- has a join with another large table with 1.500.000 records
- the query results are 150000 records

what is the reason for this difference?

Comment: Are you sure that workbench fetches ALL records instead of first N records?